# How discover (and find) all drivers that I'm using for a new minimal SO install?

Tags: debian, command-line, drivers

I'm using Debian 8 and want to formating my machine to Debian 9. I pretend to do a minimal install with just the right drivers and the necessary X modules. Everything will be done from the CLI. So, how can I discover the necessary drivers that I'm using and find them on Debian 9 (maybe the names have change?).

I have find on the web how discover my video and card drivers, but has something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of the driver through the command `lspci` then get the package name that provides this driver.

e,g:

Get the list of kernel modules driver.

```
lspci -knn
```

A sample output for the wifi driver:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:6617]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

To get the package name which provide the `ath9k` module :

```
apt-file search ath9k | less
```

The `apt-file` can be installed and updated through:

```
apt install apt-file
apt-file update
```

sample output:

```
firmware-atheros: /lib/firmware/ath9k_htc/htc_7010-1.4.0.fw
firmware-atheros: /lib/firmware/ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw
...
```

From this example the `ath9k` belong to the `firmware-atheros` pacakge. Using the package name you can [check on the official website](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) if the package is available on debian Stretch.

Comment: Apt-file doesn't worked for me, but apt-cache search yes. But your tip have help-me. Thanks a lot.

I found my graphic and wireless card drivers. There is an additional driver to install manually in my case? Or the monitor, keyboard, sound, etc, are automatically recognized?

Comment: @PeterGriffin generally it should work without problem (if you don't have any issue with debian Jessie)